# Search a pattern with spaces in unix text file

Tags: bash, unix

I've a pattern line (like below) in unix text file.
**Tue Mar 31 00:01:10 2015**
Now I want to search those lines in a file and my search criteria will be Mar 31 2015. Can I achieve this with grep.

Because my search criteria is not that simple.

Regards,

DKamran

Comment: Please add some lines of text that you are searching in, at best with at least one line of the desired target pattern to match against. Additionally, it is good habit on SO to at least post your trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.*` in the regular expression to match anything between the date and year.

```
grep "Mar 31.*2015" filename
```

To search for `is intelligent`, do:

```
grep "is .* intelligent" filename
```

Comment: Be aware, that this is a greedy match, so it could match multiple dates in the same line, so that the first "Mar 31" is matched then many "Mar 32..." and the last "2015" on the same line.

Comment: Thanks, can you Please help in achieving this as well.
Line in File: He is very intelligent boy
search criteria: is intelligent

Comment: Isn't that trivial? Do you know the basics of how to use `grep`, or are you planning on asking me for each thing you want to do?

Comment: It sounds like you need to read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below grep command.

```
grep '\bMar 31 [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\} 2015\b' file
```

`\{2\}` quantifier repeats the previous token `[0-9]` exactly two times.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with any time in the specified format in between, but not with other characters.

```
/Mar\s31\s[\d:]+\s2015/
```

You can test it [here](http://ideone.com/vfYyi9). It will print out the matching lines along with the line-number if used with `grep -nP`.